# MetricQL function inside the PromQL

Tags: grafana, promql, metricsql, pmm-server

Im using a dashboard from [here](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/14239) and it is using a function called [`topk_max`](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk_max) I found that this is from MeticQL. But Im using prometheus.

Is there any way to replicate the function in PromQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're searching for the "topk" aggregation operator.

More info at the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators).